# Overloading operator << Possible to print out two different functions?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

This is a little snippet of my code:

```
Cord::Cord(int x, int y){

  x_ = x;
  y_ = y;
}
Cord::Cord(int x, int y, int z){
  x_ = x;
  y_ = y;
  z_ = z;
}
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, Cord& x) {
  out << x.x_ << " " << x.y_ << " " << x.z_;
  return out;
}
```

Is it possible to make the operator overloading on << function for both of my function overloads. Right now if i use only the function for x and y it is also printing out z. Is there a way to make the << operator print out both functions without it printing out z when im only having x and y or is that not possible?

Comment: How is `Cord` either 2d *or* 3d, but doesn't know which? That seems fundamentally incorrect.

Comment: It is quite strange that you want 1 type to be either a 2d or 3d coordinate, or perhaps it is always a 3d coordinate and you just don't want Z to be printed if it is 0? That is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a default value for z_.

```
Cord::Cord(int x, int y){
  x_ = x;
  y_ = y;
  z_ = 0; // If 0 is a good default value for z_
}
```

With a default value, one of the solutions might be

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, Cord& x) {
  if(z_!= 0)  // If 0 is your default value for z
      out << x.x_ << " " << x.y_ << " " << x.z_;
  else
      out << x.x_ << " " << x.y_;
  return out;
}
```

Please note that your code isn't well designed.

UPDATE : Design proposition

Read about [Encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28computer_programming%29)
and [Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29)

Partial solution :

Coord2d.cpp

```
Coord2d::Coord2d(int x, int y){
  x_ = x;
  y_ = y;
}
int Coord2d::getX(){
  return x_;
}
int Coord2d::getY(){
  return y_;
}

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, Coord2d& coords2d) {
  out << x.x_ << " " << x.y_;
}
```

Coord3d.cpp

```
Coord3d::Coord3d(int x, int y, int z){
  x_ = x;
  y_ = y;
  z_ = z;
}
int Coord3d::getX(){
  return x_;
}
int Coord3d::getY(){
  return y_;
}
int Coord3d::getZ(){
  return z_;
}
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, Coord3d& coords3d) {
  out << x.x_ << " " << x.y_ << " " << x.z_;
}
```

Comment: How do you tell the difference between the default value for Z and a real value which happens to be the default?

Comment: Im just starting to learn c++, would you give any advice on how i would go about designing my code better?

Comment: @NeilKirk you can't tell. I edited my answer to suggest a new design.

Comment: Polymorphism is not relevant here.

Comment: It is, if he is printing his 2d and 3d coords without distinction right now.

Answer (score 0):

With `optional`, you may do:

```
class Coord
{
public:
    Coord(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
    Coord(int x, int y, int z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}

    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Coord& c)
    {
        out << c.x << " " << c.y;
        if (c.z) { out << " " << *c.z; }
        return out;
    }

private:
    int x;
    int y;
    boost::optional<int> z;
};
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4dfa38c241870bdc)